# Is it possible to know if a domain is using Google Apps for email?

Tags: google-workspace

I'm exchanging emails with a number of different users - is it possible to look at the mail headers and figure out if those users are using Google Apps as the mail server?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Dig their MX records:

`$> dig domainname.com mx`

If they're with Google, you'll know it.

```
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      10 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      20 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      20 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX4.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
domainname.com.            2198    IN      MX      30 ASPMX5.GOOGLEMAIL.com.
```

Comment: For windows see http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/

Comment: Also you could use http://www.samspade.org.

Comment: striking out a bit from Piskor's comment, https://www.google.com/a/example.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail with the correct domain will show you a login page and explain how to login  IF example.com is a valid google apps domain. (I just tested it)

Comment: Is there a way to identify through HTTP request ?

Comment: @ValiShah yes! you could use a public internet service to check the DNS MX records for you. try this: `curl 'https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=google.com&type=MX'`. or just visit https://dns.google.com/ and use the web interface.

Answer (score 10):

I think easiest would be just to type it into Google Domain Tester.
It does the work for you.

http://www.googledomaintester.com

Cheers!

Comment: Technically, the answer is the link. That said, if the link went down it would be *doubly* useless.

Comment: Tested: seems not working. (tested with a known g-suite enabled email)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using .NET, and make the assumption that their domain is MAIL.theirdomain.com, you can do this:

System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry("mail.theirdomain.com").HostName

Google Apps accounts that I've seen all end with google.com, such as ghs.google.com.

Paul

Comment: Writing a program to perform a DNS query with tons of existing tools seems like an overkill...

Comment: @Matteo this could be used in PowerShell, which comes with Windows Vista and newer...

Comment: That might *appear* to work, kind of - except when it won't. Many domains have a 3rd-level wildcard for A records - mail.example.com would point to the same host as xyzzy.example.com and foobar.example.com. It is better to check the actual MX record (see the accepted answer) than to guess. On half the domains I've set up with Google Apps, your method would mistakenly return "false", as the web access was not on mail.example.org. For example, this is a valid way to login: https://www.google.com/a/example.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail

Comment: or, for that matter, you can log in at mail.google.com as long as you provide your entire organizations email address eg 'helpdesk@students.abtex.edu'. Just to be fair to piskvor, I don't think this method was valid in 2012.